# Checkbox is checked change value of button (count)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some checkboxes with their number values and need to show count result in button parentheses, when one or more chceckboxes are checked:
This code I found and edited;

```js
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
    $('#count').html($('input:checkbox:checked').size());
});

$('button').text('Price is () Euro');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox">Price 10 Euro</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Price 25 Euro</label>
<label><input type="checkbox">Price 30 Euro</label>

<button id="count">Price is () Euro</button>
```

Comment: Where's the JS code you wrote in an attempt to solve this yourself? Remember that SO is here to help you *debug* code, not to write code for you

Comment: Give the inputs a value with the price. Add an event listener to the buttons, it can then use `this.value` to get the price, and write that into the button text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do-

```js
var count=0;
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    count+=Number($(this).val());
    else
    count-=Number($(this).val());
    $('button').text('Price is ('+count+') Euro');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=10>Price 10 Euro</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=25>Price 25 Euro</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value=30>Price 30 Euro</label>
        
        <button>Price is () Euro</button>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this will add the value even if the user uncheck the checkbox,

Comment: It works perfect, but I need when checkbox is unchecked, result will --

Comment: It does that check the snippet